# Analyzing Accuracy of a method to compute summation

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-mathematics

How does one analyze the accuracy of the following method to evaluate the summation?

[image]

Also, what is the difference between analyzing the accuracy and proving that it is backward stable? I think I have to prove it is backward stable, since the accuracy of solution depends on the stability of the algorithm and conditioning of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid this method.

For one thing,
if one of the $x_i$
is very large and negative,
$e^{x_i}$
will be evaluated as zero,
so the product will be zero
no matter what the other terms are.

Also,
for large positive $x_i$,
the error in
$e^{x_i}$
will be much larger
than the error in $x_i$,
since
$e^{x+c}
=e^x e^c
$,
and $c$ can be fairly large
if $x$ is quite large.